# How to remove “A N D R O I D” text at boot up?

Tags: android

At the Android 2.1 boot up i found "A N D R O I D" text . I want to hide this text or remove it. Do any one have the idea where i am storing this "A N D R O I D" text???

Comment: Do you want to do this via code in your own Android rom? Or do you just want to delete the image from your phone? If you only want to do this on you phone and it is not programming related maybe your question is better suited for superuser.com

Comment: Yaa i want to remove this text, So that next time when i boot-up my emulator it doesn't show me the "A N D R O I D" text.

Comment: For future reference: In Android 7.1.2, this string originates from console_init_action, a c++ function in init it's source code. See system/core/init/init.cpp.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need a custom ROM.

That means that your phone has to be rooted and you have to flash some updates.

I don't believe it's possible by code or by an application.

Comment: I have seen many devices like Nexus one phone, When i boot up these devices they show there own animation and not the default "A N D R O I D" Text. I want to achive the same result when i boot up for emulator

Comment: You will need a custom firmware image for your emulator to achieve that.